# Java execution blocked in socket

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

I am creating a simple client server application that let the server receive a file from the client. I implemented almost everything, but there is a moment in the excution, where the code stops, and doesn't proceed anymore.

I am not much experienced in Java, so maybe it is a trivial matter, but I can't figure out.

This is the code in the server:

```
    public static void receive(String token, String fileName, String filePath) throws IOException{

        //Stream for binary data and file transfer
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(basePath + filePath  + fileName);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

        // Variables 
        int bytesRead;

        // Bytes for store info to be sent
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16];

        //-------------------------
        // Send file 
        //------------------------- 

        System.out.println("1");

        while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            System.out.println("2");
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        System.out.println("4");

        //-------------------------
        // End of file transfer
        //-------------------------
        

        out.close();
    } // send
```

And this is the client:

```
    public static void send(Socket socket, String token, String fileName, String filePath) throws IOException{

        // Getting the file to send from the file system
        File file = new File("C:\\" + filePath + "\\" + fileName);

        // Getting length of the file and creating the buffer
        int length = (int) file.length();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

        // Setting up channels to transfer data
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

        // Variables 
        int bytesRead;

        //-------------------------
        // Send file 
        //------------------------- 

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        //-------------------------
        // End of file transfer
        //-------------------------
        in.close();
    } // send
```

In the server part, when it comes to the while loop, it prints the number 1, 2, 3, but 4 is never printed. The code get stopped or something similar, and can't proceed anymore. So, other eventual call provided by the main are blocked.

Repeat, maybe it is a trivial teorical matter, but I can't really understand why. If the loop was infinite, 2 and 3 must have been printed a lot of time, but it happens only one time. Then, I can't really see what is blocking Java from printing 4 and letting the code continuing the run.

If someone has some idea, I would be increadibly pleased. Thank you in advice

Comment: Note that almost the entire `send` function on the client side can be replaced by a call to [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)).

Comment: I should keep the socket opened. I modified the code of the application, and now it is the same, but it knows the length of the file, and both buffer have the same length, but it brakes anyway. Any suggestion about what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you allocate a large enough buffer to read the entire file.  Assuming that you actually read the file in one go, then the client will exit the loop after one write to the socket.

But there is no way visible for the server to know that the client has finished writing to the socket. The client side of the socket is not closed; therefore, more data could be coming.

I think you just need to close the socket in the client. Then the server will see an end-of-file.

If for some reason you can't close the socket (maybe you need to re-use the same connection) then you must find some other way to let the server know when the incoming file is complete.  A common way is to just send the length of the file, before the file, as a fixed-length value (say, 4- or 8-byte binary).

Comment: I should keep the socket opened. I modified the code of the application, and now it is the same, but it knows the length of the file, and both buffer have the same length, but it brakes anyway. Any suggestion about what should I do?

Comment: Buffer sizes have nothing to do with it. `read(buffer)` will only return <= 0 on an end-of-file, so if you haven't changed that loop and have not arranged to generate end-of-file , then you're stuck in the loop.  Fundamentally, the issue is that TCP does not have "messages", it just sends bytes.